# Does anyone know where else to download the package clustsig? It can't handle my version of R

Tags: r

I get this message, but can't find the package anywere else

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘clustsig’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: What version of R are you using?  What does  `sessionInfo()` say?

Comment: The package is no longer maintained. Here is the message: "Package ‘clustsig’ was removed from the CRAN repository. Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive." The [clustsig archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/clustsig/) where you can get older versions of the program. The package maintainer is listed as Douglas Whitaker <whitaker@ufl.edu> so you might contact him directly.

Answer (score 0):

The package is no longer maintained but the source code is on github and looks 'fine' to me so it should still run as expected using current versions of R (although there are lots of "TODO" / "UPDATE THIS" / commented-out code chunks throughout, so it was clearly under development before being 'abandoned').

If you want to install it, you can use the [devtools package](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools) to download and install it directly from the github CRAN mirror:

```r
library(devtools)
#> Loading required package: usethis
install_github("cran/clustsig")
#> Downloading GitHub repo cran/clustsig@HEAD
#> ✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/gf/3p_ynkts411bs238rtw3y0b40000gn/T/RtmpriR9AY/remotes3ce54af7cf6/cran-clustsig-88fbd6a/DESCRIPTION’ ...
#> ─  preparing ‘clustsig’:
#> ✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
#> ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
#> ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
#> ─  building ‘clustsig_1.1.tar.gz’
#>    
#> * installing *source* package ‘clustsig’ ...
#> ** using staged installation
#> ** R
#> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
#> ** help
#> *** installing help indices
#> ** building package indices
#> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
#> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
#> ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
#> * DONE (clustsig)

library(clustsig)

data("USArrests")
usarrests<-USArrests[,c(1,2,4)]
rownames(usarrests)<-state.abb
# Run simprof on the data
res <- simprof(data=usarrests, 
               method.distance="braycurtis")
#> Warning: This version of the Bray-Curtis index does not use standardization.
#> Warning: To use the standardized version, use "actual-braycurtis".
#> Warning: See the help documentation for more information.
# Graph the result
simprof.plot(res)
```

[image]

```
#> 'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 50 members total, at height 42.16072
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>